How do I revert git checkout from a feature branch?
I'm new to git.
I generally create a new feature branch from master & then work on the task.
Recently, I executed git checkout instead of git switch when moving from master to my existing feature branch.
The highlighted commit when pushed introduced 50+ new unwanted changes in my pull request in git.

How can I revert this?
There are 2 more commits pushed above the highlighted commit.
In my feature branch, I tried git revert <sha_id> but it failed.
git revert dc431355891d10da17fd7a7e327da93a7ca23ea3
error: commit dc431355891d10da17fd7a7e327da93a7ca23ea3 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed

I tried giving -m but that also failed.
git revert dc431355891d10da17fd7a7e327da93a7ca23ea3 -m "[Story_id] reverting unwanted checkout"
error: option `mainline' expects a number greater than zero


The error message says that you should use git revert -m ...

I tried -m also, but it did not work. I'm googling this new error, getting solutions related to cherry pick. What is that?

git checkout does not create any changes that have not been already there before. There should not be anything to undo. Maybe you want to undo something else that you did in addition to git checkout.

Read the man page for git revert. It tells how -m should be used.


introduced 50+ new unwanted changes - you can make git reset to a previous commit, and recommit in whatever different pieces you want it to become. After that git push -f should be used.


Checkout and switch commands are functionally the same in this context (checkout is a swiss knife though)

There is no substantial difference between git checkout and git switch. Whatever you did, these commands are not what causes your confusion. What it is that confuses you cannot be said, because you did not show what else you did.

git reset to the correct point. git cherry-pick to get the commits made after the merge.
